# I can ping but can't browse

Tags: networking, internet

I have Xubuntu 14.04 with the latest update and having issues connecting to the university's network. I'm running xubuntu on my chromebook and the internet works at home but I just started school and I'm on campus at the moment and can't get it to work. I went to the school's tech support but no one has any experience with xubuntu or linux.

I am able to get the internet to work on my android tablet and on my chromebook when running chrome. I don't have any proxy settings or ever set any and I have tried different browsers. I was able to ping google and no packets were loss. I'm wondering if it could it be on the university's side because they have a program that sets up the internet for mac and windows but not linux. I set it the network connection manually and tried different security settings.

Comment: What is that "program that sets up the internet for Mac and Windows" called? You say you have internet working on your Android tablet and Chrome OS. Did you have to go through that "program" to set up internet?

Comment: The program is called SafeConnect. And no, I did not have to go through the program to get the internet working on my other devices. I did it manually by selecting wpa2 enterprise and the security method.

Comment: And you obviously tried doing that in Ubuntu but it didn't work, correct? What's the output of `curl -I google.com` and `telnet google.com 80`?